# How do I Install the "Basic Server" Profile onto a "Minimal" Install of CentOS 6?

Tags: centos6

Ok, I swear I know how to do this! However, it appears to have slipped my mind, and it's starting to frustrate me that I can't remember...  ;)

If I install CentOS 6 without the Anaconda installer it will install a "minimal" install by default.  However, the minimal install is missing basic utilities such as wget, and I would like to install the "basic server" profile onto it after-the-fact.

So, to summarize:  **How do I Install the "Basic Server" Profile onto a "Minimal" Install of CentOS?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is to install the 'Base' yum group

```
yum groupinstall Base
```

In order to know what packages are provided by the group

```
yum groupinfo Base
```

The list of all available group is available with

```
yum grouplist
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you so much...  Any longer, and I was going to go nuts trying to remember!  ;)